# How to store Javascript output into a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hi I wanted to know how I could store a javascript calculation into a form instead of it being an alert or just written out in another page? Below is my Javascript code, which calculates price.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getQuote() {
        var qtyvar = document.getElementById("qty").value;
        var qlyvar= document.getElementById("qly").value;
        var quote;
        if (qlyvar=="basic") {
            quote=10*qtyvar;
        }
        else if (qlyvar=="medium") {
            quote=15*qtyvar;
        }
        else if (qlyvar=="high") {
            quote=20*qtyvar;
        }
alert('£' + quote);
```

}

This script is run when this button is pressed

```
<p><input class="mybutton" name="Quote" value="Calculate quote" onclick="getQuote();"></p>
```

How can I store the result of the Javascript into the button or inside the form? Hopefully I explained this clearly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a hidden input field inside the form

```
<input name="quotation" id="quotation" type="hidden">
```

And in place of alert in the Js, you can have

```
document.getElementById("quotation").value = quote;
```

For your reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/5tV02Tbc6YWTiYKJOtVE?p=preview

Comment: Where would I put inside the form? After the Calculate quote?

Comment: The input will already be there inside the form. Only the value will be getting updated whenever you click on the button.

Comment: Hi @nikhil sorry i tried your method, but I cannot see the hidden field with the calculation appear after I press the button.

Comment: @YasMan - I have added a working plunker in answer for your reference. Please check.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer in plunker but when I click calculate, it doesn't show the result of the calculation.

Comment: @YasMan - Your question appeared that you wanted the answer in form (hidden). However, now it seems you want to see the results too. Please refer to updated plunker at `http://plnkr.co/edit/5tV02Tbc6YWTiYKJOtVE?p=preview`

Comment: @YasMan - happy to help you

Answer (score 3):

You can put hidden field in your form, then when click the button set the hidden field value with result.

```
<input type='hidden' id='result_hdn' value=''>
```

Then is code:

```
document.getElementById("result_hdn").value= quote;
```

Comment: Hi Sorry, I tried using your method but when I press the get quote button, nothing shows up

Comment: Your button mustn't submit the form, does it do?

Comment: HI @Gouda no that button is used, just to calculate the price and give the quote. Before it was being outputted in an alert box and I want the output to be in a field.

Comment: Did you put the HTML hidden field in your form?

Comment: Sorry where would I put that? is it when i declare the form?

Comment: <input type='hidden' id='result_hdn' value=''> this should be inside your form tag